# mysql "KEEP ONLY" command?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I know that there is a `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <exprs>` command in mysql that deletes tuples from the specified table if the expressions are valid.

However, it becomes a burden always using demorgan's law in taking the complement of keep only expressions.

**My question is, is there a `KEEP ONLY` type of command for mysql?** I tried looking everywhere, but only came across examples of taking the complements of expressions and then using the DELETE command.

Comment: no. there isn't. if you want to keep records, then you have to write your `where` clause so that it excludes them.

Comment: thanks. just curious though, would it be so hard to implement such a command?

Comment: no idea. I've never ever had to deal with mysql at the source code level. you'd be talking about building in an entire new branch into the sql parser, at minimum. and then it wouldn't be mysql anymore. it'd "ct12sql" and incompatible with pretty much the rest of the mysql universe.

Comment: ... I think people would like ct12sql for having both delete and keep... haha. thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out another way to structure a "KEEP ONLY" type of command!

Say you want have something like this:

```
KEEP the tuples that satisfy <massive_expression>
```

All you have to do is negate `<massive_expression>` in the DELETE command, like so:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ! (massive_expression);
```

It makes total sense, I should have seen this before!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like KEEP ONLY.  However, it's not usually as hard as DeMorgan's Law to invert a result set.

Imagine you have some query to produce the results you want to keep. Remember that tables generally have some kind of primary key. What you want to do is select those columns. Often, this is a surrogate key (ID column), and it's as easy as selecting that a column:

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE X
```

What you can do is nest the query:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE X)
```

It's also common to write that as a JOIN, instead of a NOT IN, but as the whole point of this answer was to simplify your logical process for producing this code, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. I will add, however, that if your primary key has more than one column, you may have to write that JOIN code.